# Partitioning a basis of a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose I have a basis $B$ of a direct sum $V\oplus W$ of finite dimensional vector spaces. I’d like to show that we can find a partition $B=B'\coprod B''$ such that $p_V(B')$ and $p_W(B'')$ are bases of $V$ and $W$ respectively, where $p_V$ and $p_W$ are the projections from $V\oplus W$ to $V$ and $W$ respectively.

I have managed to show this in case $V$ is one dimensional, but not much else.